# What's the difference between management.server.port and management.port properties?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

To run Actuator on a separate port we write `management.server.port: 9001` in the application.properties file. 
But there is a confusing line in [Actuator Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) code:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"management.port=0"})
```

And then 
...

```
@Value("${local.management.port}")
private int mgt;
```

Here is the source class https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-actuator-service/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/HelloWorldApplicationTests.java

What's the difference between
 `management.server.port`, 
`management.port` and
 `local.management.port`?

Comment: Link is broken, the correct one could be; https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-actuator-service/blob/main/complete/src/test/java/com/example/actuatorservice/HelloWorldApplicationTests.java

Answer (score 15):

The `management.server.port` is used to expose management/actuator endpoints to a different HTTP port other than the one used for running the application.

And the `management.port=0` is used to provide random port for the actuator to run while integration testing.

Whereas `local.management.port` is used to inject the random port.

Reference [Spring Boot Actuator: Production-ready features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) and [Random Port for Actuator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4424)